# How to validate a signature using just the public key of the signing authority? C#

Tags: c#, encryption, signature, code-signing-certificate

I have an encrypted XML which is signed using the private key of a signing certificate. I have decrypted the XML on another machine, revealing the public key of the same signing cert within it. Before I process the data that I have unwrapped, I need to **validate the signature on the encrypted XML**. How do I do this using **just the public key** of the signing cert that was used to sign it in the first place?
I am working with C# for this application.

Comment: Provide some more details. How is the XML signed? It is signed as binary data *(in this case it is absolutely irrelevant, that the signed data is XML)*, or it is some XML signing *(e. g. SOAP with inner XML data containing the certificate and signature within the XML)*? For each type you need different approach.